# Converting base-10 to base2 in Ruby using recursion (Binary converter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, recursion, binary

I would like to convert a base10 number to base2 in Ruby *without* using the built in to_s(2) method, using **recursion**.

I wrote this:

```
def to_binary(d)  
  if d<1   
    return ""
  else
    return to_binary(d/2).to_s + (d%2).to_s
  end
end
```

This would return all correct results EXCEPT 0. Is there any way to return 0 for 0 without having leading zeroes for numbers greater than 0?

Comment: Please learn to format your code correctly. It'll help you detect errors and others read your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your checks a bit:

```
def to_binary(d)  
  return d.to_s if [0,1].include?(d) # same as "if d == 0 || d == 1"
  to_binary(d/2) + (d%2).to_s
end

to_binary(10) == "1010"
#=> true
to_binary(0) == "0"
#=> true
```

---

You could also write above method as:

```
def to_binary(d)  
  return d.to_s if [0,1].include?(d)

  div,mod = d.divmod(2)
  to_binary(div) + mod.to_s
end
```